# R: Retrieve index of a string in a list of vectors of strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a beginner to R. I have a data frame `foo` like

```
a       b    c
"a"     1.0  1
"b,c"   0.9  2
"a,b"   0.8  3
```

For now, i am only interested in column `foo$a`. What I need to do is calculate the rank of each possible entry in `foo$a`.
I have done

```
foo$a <- strsplit(foo$a, ",", fixed=T)
```

in order to get a list of those entries. I know that there exist only 9 possible entries, which i have stored in a vector `entries`.

I want to add a column to `foo` for each possible entry in `entries`, holding the index of that entry in `foo$a`. For the example given above, my desired output would be:

```
a       b    c   rankA   rankB   rankC
"a"     1.0  1       1      NA      NA
"b,c"   0.9  2      NA       1       2
"a,b"   0.8  3       1       2      NA
```

**Is there a built-in function in R which I can utilize in order to get there?**
I tried `match` and `%in%`, but so far I wasn't able to figure out how to get them to work on the list of vectors, which `foo$a` is.

Comment: match is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
L        = strsplit(as.character(df[,1]),',')
vals     = unique(unlist(L))
newNames = paste0('rank', vals)

cbind(df, `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(L, match, x=vals)), newNames))

#    a   b c ranka rankb rankc
#1   a 1.0 1     1    NA    NA
#2 b,c 0.9 2    NA     1     2
#3 a,b 0.8 3     1     2    NA
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "a,b", 
"b,c"), class = "factor"), b = c(1, 0.9, 0.8), c = 1:3), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to understand the functions you used and did for most of them (cbind, rbind, lapply). However, I can't  wrap my head around `\`colnames<-\`(...)`. `colnames(...)` is a function and `\`<-\`` is the assignOp-function derived from its infix notation. But what is `\`colnames<-\`(...)` and why can we give it 2 arguments?

Comment: `\`colanmes<-\`` is simply the function associated to `colnames` taking as argument the object to name and the names ... like f(object, newnames). It returns the object with the new column names.

Comment: How is this concept called? If I understand correcly, S has a LISP background. I was familiar with the prefix notation of infix functions, but didnt knew that concept.
It certainly isn't the same as calling `colnames(object) <- newnames`, as this doesnt return object and won't let me construct the object there in the first place. ("Error: target of assignment expands to non-language object") I'd like to read more about this language feature.